# How can I reduce this part of my code so that its not repetitive

Tags: python

Is it possible to reduce this part of my code in size?

```
for i in range(0,9,3):
    print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
```

So pretty much I am making a tic tac toe game, and this is the code for my gameboard for tic tac toe. I am pasting this exact code many times; thus, why I want to reduce it in size. Since its long and big it would be a hassle to correct all of it if a problem were to occur. So anyways is there a way to make it so its smaller/easier to code? I attempted to make it a variable but it didn't work.

Comment: Put it into a function.

Comment: And how would I do that exactly?

Comment: Just like any other function. `def print_board():` followed by the code.

Comment: But why are you pasting the code multiple times? Your code should be in a loop, you should only need to print the board once each time through the loop.

Comment: What exactly is long and repeatativ and these four lines of code?

Comment: Well, I have many if statements for each way you can win tic tac toe (across, diagonal, etc) and under each if statement I have to re paste the game board so that it shows it when someone wins or they tie. If that makes sense

Comment: Klaus, long was the wrong word to use, but since I am using this exact code many times, if a error were to be in that section of code it would take a while to fix that error every time I pasted it.

Comment: Barmar, I am struggling to use functions as I have not learned it yet. Would you be able to put it in a function for me? I have tried and gotten a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items in `board` are strings then you can use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on chunks from it

```py
print('\n------------\n'.join([' | '.join(board[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,9,3)]))
```

If `board` don't contain strings you can make a new temporary list

```py
strings = [str(x) for x in board]
print('\n------------\n'.join([' | '.join(strings[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,9,3)]))
```

But as Barmar says you should put it in a function if you use it in several places

Define the function in the beginning of the script

```py
def print_board(board):
    for i in range(0,9,3):
        print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
        if (i<6):
            print("------------")
```

And then just call the function wherever you want the board printed

```py
print_board(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store grid template in separate text file and update it with player's turns:

`grid.txt`:

```
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
```

Code:

```
CELLS = {'1': 9, '2': 11, '3': 13, '4': 25, '5': 27, '6': 29, '7': 41, '8': 43, '9': 45}

with open('grid.txt', 'r') as f:
    grid = f.read()

print(grid)
players = ['X', 'O']
while True:
    turn = input(f'{players[0]} make your turn [1-9]: ')
    index = CELLS[turn]
    grid = f'{grid[:index]}{players[0]}{grid[index+1:]}'
    players.reverse()
    print(grid)
```

Play the game:

```
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
X make your turn [1-9]: 5
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
| |X| |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
O make your turn [1-9]: 1
|-|-|-|
|O| | |
|-|-|-|
| |X| |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
X make your turn [1-9]: 3
|-|-|-|
|O| |X|
|-|-|-|
| |X| |
|-|-|-|
| | | |
|-|-|-|
```